# DocumentFilter in java and ctrl+v is not working

Tags: java, copy-paste, documentfilter

When I'm trying to use of this DocumentFilter the ctrl+v and ctrl+c is not working.

```
public class stringLengthTrim extends DocumentFilter {

private int limit;

public stringLengthTrim(int limit) {
    this.limit = limit;
}

@Override
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
    Document innerDoc = fb.getDocument();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(innerDoc.getText(0, innerDoc.getLength()));
    sb.insert(offset, string);
    if (textOK(sb.toString())) {
        super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }
}

@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    Document innerDoc = fb.getDocument();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(innerDoc.getText(0, innerDoc.getLength()));
    int start = offset;
    int end = offset + length;
    sb.replace(start, end, text);
    if (textOK(sb.toString())) {
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
    }
}

@Override
public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
        throws BadLocationException {
    super.remove(fb, offset, length);
}

private boolean textOK(String text) {
    if (text.length() <= limit) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

what can i do ? i'm using this documentfilter just for control the length of input text.is another way to restrict the length of JTextarea or JTextfield?

`how to set documentfilter to support ctrl+v and ctrl+c?`

`and this is usage:`

```
PlainDocument cID = (PlainDocument) contentID.getDocument();
cID.setDocumentFilter(new stringLengthTrim(9));
```

the `contentID` is a JTextarea.

Comment: It works for me.  Can you be more specific than “is not working”?  What behavior are you seeing?  It would help if you edit your question and include the code which installs this DocumentFilter on your JTextField or JTextArea.

Comment: when i'm trying to past a text in JTextarea or JTextfield with ctrl+v the cpoied text is not past.        `PlainDocument cID = (PlainDocument) contentID.getDocument();
        cID.setDocumentFilter(new stringLengthTrim(9));`

Comment: And are you pasting fewer than ten characters?

Comment: very thanks @VGR . the problem is solved. my copied text is over maximum. i'm working very hard and i'm so tired ;-)